# I would like to fetch text with color from web table and print in excel using selenium web driver and apache poi

Tags: java, selenium

I get color of the text and stored in 'textColor'. Now i need to pass this color to font.setColor. I mean instead of hard code color, i need to pass the textColor to font.setColor which mean i need to place it instead of Light_ORANGE. Could anyone help me to fix this. At the end i need to extract the text with color and the same text with color need to be write in excel.

WebElement winner = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@url='/api/html/cricket-scorecard/23253']/div[1]"));

```
    String textColor = winner.getCssValue("color");
    System.out.println(textColor);

    Pattern c = Pattern.compile("rgba *\\(*([0-9]+), *([0-9]+), *([0-9]+), *([0-9]+) *\\)");
    Matcher m = c.matcher(textColor);
    m.matches();

    Color awtColor = new Color(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)), Integer.valueOf(m.group(2)), Integer.valueOf(m.group(3)), Integer.valueOf(m.group(4)));

    File file = new File("D:\\SELVA\\24GB\\Cucumber-Project\\scorecard.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sh = wb.createSheet("Scorecard");
    XSSFCell cell = sh.createRow(0).createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(winner.getText());
    XSSFFont xssfFont = wb.createFont();
    XSSFColor xssfColor = new XSSFColor(awtColor);
    xssfFont.setColor(xssfColor);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(fos);
    wb.close();
```

Comment: In the second revision of your code, you declared the `xssfFont`, but did **NOT use** it and you didn't apply `xssfFont` (which belongs to `CellStyle`) to the `cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String textColor = winner.getCssValue("color");` returns a String, such as `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)`.

You can modify your code refer to this example:

```java
import java.awt.Color;

Pattern c = Pattern.compile("rgba *\\( *([0-9]+), *([0-9]+), *([0-9]+), *([0-9]+) *\\)");
Matcher m = c.matcher(textColor);
/*
 * The code will be more robust if add validation of `textColor` content 
 */
m.matches();

Color awtColor = new Color(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)),  // r
                           Integer.valueOf(m.group(2)),  // g
                           Integer.valueOf(m.group(3)),  // b
                           Integer.valueOf(m.group(4))); // a

XSSFColor xssfColor = new XSSFColor(awtColor);
xssfFont.setColor(xssfColor);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Peter. However, showing below error.......java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found  at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536) . Can you look into this

Comment: @SelvaSPM Wow, I made a mistake of missing a sentence. The answer has been corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Peter. I have added m.matches(); along with XSSFFont xssfFont = wb.createFont();. I have edited my code and copied above. Now the code is running without error. But, the expected text only prints and it does not print with the color. Could you please help. I took https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/23253/eng-vs-pak-3rd-t20i-pakistan-tour-of-england-2020. I spent two days, but still the desired color output is not getting printed. Kindly help me. Sure i will click USEFUL button.

Comment: hi @SelvaSPM , after you edited your code, some necessary statements disappeared, you could compare the code difference between the two versions. So, in other words, after `xssfFont.setColor(xssfColor);`, add 
`
XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle)wb.createCellStyle();
style.setFont(xssfFont);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
`

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, it is working fine after correcting code as per your help.

Comment: @SelvaSPM Glad to hear that